# Ruby Regex: Scan for string if line doesn't start with >

Tags: ruby, regex, exit

I need to scan a text file for an occurrence of "attach" on a line that doesn't begin with a >. If I find attach, I exit with a 1, otherwise, a 0

Here's an example:

```
>hello!
>foo
>bag
>whatever
attach
```

And that example would exit with a 1.

```
>attach
>foo
>too
```

This example would have exited with a 0, since the only occurrence of attach appears on a line starting with a >.

This is an outline of what I have so far, but the syntax escapes me for how I'd do this with a Ruby Regex:

```
text = IO.read(ARGV[0]).scan(/^"[attach]"/)exit!(1)
exit(0)
```

So the idea here is that I fulfill whatever requirement scan is doing, and immediately exit with a 1 if I found attach.

So any insight would be great! (Note: I'm not allowed to use a loop!)

NOTE: "attach" needs only to appear on a line, anywhere in the line. So a line looking like this:

```
file hello attach hi
```

would exit with a 1.

EDIT:

The following is the current test.txt file I am running against. My syntax for running this is, under 1.9.3,

ruby attach.rb test.txt

and then I echo out the return:

echo $?

This is the file, named test.txt

```
> attach
> hello!
> how are you?
attach
```

That file SHOULD return a 1.

Using that file, here's what I WANT to see:

```
-bash-4.1$ ruby attach.rb test.txt
-bash-4.1$ echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
text = IO.read(ARGV[0]).scan(/^(?!>).*?attach/)
```

The zero-width negative forward assertion allows you to match not-> without consuming part of the source (which may be, in the first example, the 'a' of attach).

Requested transcript:

```
julian@maw learn $ cat f
> attach
> hello!
> how are you?
attach
julian@maw learn $ irb
2.0.0-p0 :001 > text = IO.read('f').scan(/^(?!>).*?attach/)
 => ["attach"] 
2.0.0-p0 :002 > 

julian@maw learn $ cat g
> attach
> hello!
> how are you?
> also >'d attach
julian@maw learn $ irb
2.0.0-p0 :001 > text = IO.read('g').scan(/^(?!>).*?attach/)
 => [] 
2.0.0-p0 :002 >
```

Comment: That looks great, but, it's still returning 0 when it shouldn't be

Comment: If the word "attach" appears on a line that DOES NOT start with a >, then return 1. If there are no such occurrences, return 0.

Comment: (For the record, the DOES NOT was capitalized for emphasis, not frustration)

Comment: ... and why do you think my code doesn't work in that case?  Do you want me to include a transcript of running it over an example like that?

Comment: That would be great, because when I run the file it doesn't work. I will update the question to include the current test.txt file I am running it against.

Comment: It looks like that's what I need, but the way I run it and interpret the output may be screwing me. Which is unfortunate, because there's only 1 accepted output for this problem.  If you read the EDIT portion of my question, that should show you what I'm looking for?

Comment: OK, I've provided and explained the regex, in response to your question.  The regex works just fine for what you want to do.  Your task is now to exit with 0 on [] or else 1 on not-[].  Since you've done this already, you should be able to do it again.  Sorry to be blunt, but I've got to get back to work.

Comment: No no, don't apologize, I really appreciate your help. We haven't covered if else yet, so that's what's throwing me. I'll look it up, thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: `scan` is an overkill for this purpose. You should use `=~` or `match`.